# Print sequence of increasing adjacent sequential numbers in an NxN matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Question:
Given a NxN matrix which contains all distinct 1 to n^2 numbers, write code to print sequence of increasing adjacent sequential numbers.

ex:
1 5 9
 
2 3 8 
4 6 7

should print 
6 7 8 9

The above is what I have been seeing asked on another coding website, but the question is not explained in detail. However there are many folks attempting with solutions, so it makes me believe that I am missing a crucial piece in the question domain. Not sure if posting questions from other websites is against SO rules, so I will give it a shot. If it is, apologies in advance. But not being able to understand the question is driving me nuts!
Original Question URL: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5147801809846272

My thought process is: Matrices are usually read 1 row at a time - top down. I am unable to see 6 7 8 9 as adjacent numbers, unless seen visually. matrix [row] [column] is the general declaration i have seen till now. So how is the question seeing 6 7 8 9 as adjacent?

Comment: the example here is missing some important formatting. You should fix it so that it's a 3x3 matrix as it is in your source url.

Comment: yes, you're right. I'm still trying to get my head around how to key in a matrix in the right format.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the solution totally depends on how "adjacent" is defined and Im hazarding a guess that here it means numbers which are either on the same row or column.

[Spiral Matrix](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/) is an example of how to go traverse matrix from outside to inside. I guess you can use this and keep track of sequences and print them out.

Comment: I agree the solution depends on how "adjacent" is defined, and that is what I am missing. Your spiral matrix example looks similar. If I were to create an approach keeping that in mind, I would first look row by row, in a spiral fashion, for a matching pattern and then go column by column, when I would spot the pattern. Do you see any issue with this approach?

Comment: Adding to above: (Even with this, only when I start traversing in following order will I see the pattern:4 2 1 5 3 6 7 8 9-so after trying a regular start point - 0,0; i will have to switch the start points to each of the 4 corners to identify pattern)

Comment: I am assuming my logic above is good enough to work with an interviewer and proceed with a couple of options at hand, which can then be modified as required. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Right. so its slightly painful ,but then the question itself isnt very clear. I would say choose a direction and go with it. And of course you might need to look at other direction also. But cannot think of a better way to atm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the numbers in cells instead of a matrix,

```
 - - -
|1|5|9|
 - - -
|2|3|8|
 - - -
|4|6|7|
 - - -
```

In my understanding, adjacent means numbers of which cells share an edge.

In that case the answer can be find in `O(n^2)` time using following algorithm

```
maxChain = 0
for each i = n to 1 do
    if (i < n) and (i+1 is adjacent to i)
        currentChain = currentChain + 1
    else
        currentChain = 1
    maxChain = max(maxChain, currentChain)
end
```

Here maxChain is your answer. Inside the loop currentChain denotes length of the maximum adjacent sequence of the form i, i+1, i+2 ...